# Edite https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/admin/people/profileCardProperties

Tags: json, http, post, patch, profile

please help me)
I need to add atribute "ipPhone" in profileCardProperties. please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOdHU.png)

{
"directoryPropertyName": "ipPhone"
}

"error": {
"code": "UnknownError",
"message": "{    "error": {        "code": "400",        "message": "",        "innerError": {            "peopleAdminErrorCode": "PeopleAdminValidationFailure",            "peopleAdminValidationError": "{"DirectoryPropertyName":["DirectoryPropertyName is not supported."]}",            "peopleAdminRequestId": "a0627d6e-816e-a2c3-19d7-6da16036695a",            "peopleAdminClientRequestId": "dbe733ae-2e17-0fb5-4505-5b53df00b4f9",            "date": "2024-02-23T08:50:37.4310491Z"        }     } }",